# Predictive model in R

Tags: r, regression, machine-learning, time-series, neural-networks

I have the data of events occurring randomly. Variables include, Unique ID,type, Date of Event, End date etc. I have the dates of, when the event occurs for 6 years. I need to predict the next occurrence of the event or the next few occurrences in the following month or year. The frequency of events increase as time increases. What is the best approach to this problem.